# How is the decision to own a USB hub device and host made?

Tags: usb-device, usb-host, usb-hub

I'm doing research. I am using a TUSB2046 USB hub. I just started researching this topic. How does the TUSB2046 or other hubs decide the host and the device when the device connection is made with the host? I looked at the data sheet, but I couldn't find any information about it. How is the decision to have a device or a house made? Is it done with a pin connection or software?

Comment: The pins DP0/DM0 are the root port, i.e. the single port towards the computer. The four other DPx/DMx pairs are the ports to connect devices to.

Comment: In other words, it is the host computer that connects to the DP0 and DM0 pins. The other 4 pins are connected to the device connection. That's right? @Codo

Comment: Yes. If it's a USB hub in its own case, it'll likely have a fixed cable with an USB-A connector for the hub, and four USB-A sockets for the devices.